# Calcular el total de sumar los dos productos que tengo en mi programa y que los muestre por el tag Total

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consigo capturar el 0 que pertenece a total y consigo que ambos productos en la tag de subtotales haga el cálculo, como por ejemplo, si compro 2 productos por 25 me muestra 50, pero quiero ambos productos y al pulsar el botón me muestre el total en la casilla Total.

Para esto, estoy usando la función `calculAll` pero no consigo sacar dicho valor.

Aquí pego el js donde solo me falta obtener la suma del total del productos. Por más que lo intento no consigo dar con la tecla, ¿es por que tengo que hacer dos subtotales diferentes? es decir, de cada uno de los subtotales, ¿almacenar el valor y luego sumarlo?

Quiero que haga la suma cuando hago click en el evento que cree en la función `createProduct`, una vez que hago click me muestra los subtotales de los productos pero no me realiza la suma total.

```
function updateSubtotal(product) {
     
    const price = product.querySelector('.price span')
    const priceElement = parseFloat(price.innerText)
     
    const quantity = product.querySelector('.i').value
    let quantityElement = quantity
     
    let subtotal = product.querySelector('.subtotal span')
    subtotal.innerText = priceElement * quantityElement
    console.log(subtotal)
}


function calculateAll(subtotal) {

    const firstProduct = document.querySelector('.rubber')   
    const secondProduct = document.querySelector('.beach')

    updateSubtotal(firstProduct)   updateSubtotal(secondProduct)

    let subTotalPrice = document.querySelectorAll('.subtotal span')

    subTotalPrice.forEach((i) => {
    let allSubTotalPrice = subTotalPrice[i]
    let totalPrice = document.querySelector('.total-value span')
    totalPrice.innerText = allSubTotalPrice

    function createProduct() {
        
    }
 
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const calculatePricesBtn = 
    document.getElementById('calculate')
    calculatePricesBtn.addEventListener('click', calculateAll)
 
    const removeElement = document.getElementById('remove')
    removeElement.addEventListener('click', removeProduct)
 
    })
```

Comment: Nos falta saber cuando llamas a esas funciones de javascript. En el código que has puesto en la pregunta no las llamas nunca, por lo tanto no sabemos realmente cuando esperas su ejecución ni podemos reproducir tu problema para ayudarte.  Edita tu pregunta agregándolo y quizás sea reabierta.

Comment: Buenas, espero haberla ya editado bien, gracias de antemano!

Comment: No, lo siento, no lo has hecho bien. Tu código no cierra bien las llaves, da muchos errores de sintaxis, y no es funcional. Y el texto de tu pregunta también aparece con problemas de formato. Si tu no te esmeras en presentarnos una buena pregunta, con el código bien puesto y con un texto descriptivo bien formateado, poco podremos hacer para reabrirla, lo siento. Léete [ask], [tour] y [example] para aprender mejor como funciona este sitio y para hacer mejores preguntas que obtengan mejores respuestas.

Comment: Cuando estes editando una pregunta, pulsa sobre el **?** que aparece a la derecha en la cabecera del editor para aprender bien el funcionamiento del mismo y el formateo con [Markdown](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) usado en este sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que creo que tienes mal pegado el código, creo que a la funcion calculateAll le falta un parentesis, además de que no se le envía ningún parámetro.

Aún así, en el foreach, si todos los subtotales de los productos están bien, puedes hacer esto:

```
const total = 0;
subTotalPrice.forEach((i) => {
    let elemPrice = Number(i.value);
    total += elemPrice;
}
let totalPriceElem = document.querySelector('.total-value span')
totalPriceElem.innerText = total
```

Answer (score -1):

o yo estoy viendo mal, o tu funcion updateSubtotal no tiene un return (por lo tanto no devuelve datos (solo te lo muestra en pantalla)

Comment: Ya tienes puntuación suficiente como para dejar comentarios en las preguntas.